# What are some problems that have higher degree of unsolvalbilty than $\Pi^0_2$-complete problems?

Tags: computability, undecidability

I'm looking for some problems that have higher degree of unsolvalbilty in term of arithmetical hierarchy that requires more than 2 quantifiers like $\Pi^0_3$ ,$\Pi^0_4$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, Soare's old book *Recursively enumerable sets and degrees* gives a few examples. Here are a couple off the top of my head (below I fix some standard enumeration $(W_e)_{e\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the r.e. sets):

- The set of $e$ such that $W_e$ is recursive is $\Sigma^0_3$-complete.
- The set of $e$ such that $W_e$ is co-infinite (= has infinite complement) is  $\Pi^0_3$-complete.
- Let $G_e$ be the directed graph on $\mathbb{N}$ with an edge from $a$ to $b$ iff $\langle a,b\rangle\in W_e$ (where "$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$" is your favorite pairing function). Then we can ask about index sets corresponding to graph properties, e.g. the set of $e$ such that $G_e$ is connected and so forth. This gives rise to an **extremely** complicated index set: the set of $e$ such that $G_e$ has no infinite path is $\Pi^1_1$-complete. **Note the superscript** - "$\Pi^1_1$" takes us well outside the entire arithmetic hierarchy!